# How to trigger WinForms button click from remote thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms

I've got an application that I've developed in VB 2010.  It consists of a series of Windows forms and a listener process which listens to input from a MIDI device (a keyboard etc).  This listener process runs in a separate thread.

Using a callback function and the invoke method I can update the value of a text box on one of the forms with the value of the notes played on the MIDI device (code below).

What I can't seem to do is to trigger a button press on one of the buttons so that a piece of code runs on the same form using another callback function and invoke.

I've Googled around and can't find any working examples so I'm not sure that this is possible - I hope it is because this is the last 1% of my project !

Here's what works to update a text box on the form, what would I need to modify in order to click a button on the same form called btn_NextSection ?

```
' Because the MIDI listener process runs in a different thread
' it can read the states of controls on the parent form but it
' cannot modify them so we need to identify the parent process
' and update the text box as that one instead

' Set up the callback
Private Delegate Sub SetNextSectionTextCallback(ByVal [text] As String)

' Updates NextSection
Private Sub SetNextSectionText(ByVal [text] As String)
    ' Function to see if the thread that tries to update the
    ' text box is the same as the one that started it.  If it
    ' isn't then locate parent process and update as that one
    If callerInstance.txt_NextSection.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New SetNextSectionTextCallback(AddressOf SetNextSectionText)
        callerInstance.Invoke(d, New Object() {[text]})
    Else
        callerInstance.txt_NextSection.Text = [text]
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: So you want to simulate the appearance of the button being clicked (the visual effect?), or do you want to trigger the code that gets run in the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to run the code, not simulate the button click, try something like this. Invoke requires a function so you may need to create a dummy return object.

```
Private Sub btn_NextSection_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btn_NextSection.Click
    NextSection()
End Sub

Private Function NextSection() As Object
    'do something on the UI thread
    Return Nothing ' to satisfy the requirements of Invoke
End Function

Private Sub AnotherThreadHere()
    'call NextSection on the UI thread
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, New Action(Function() NextSection()))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pat and you're right, I do want to run the code which is located in another form.  I've tried your suggestion but there are two issues.  Firstly, I don't have System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs - I do have System.Windows.Forms but there's no RoutedEventArgs option.  And secondly I don't have access to Application.Current.Dispatcher

Comment: I'm sorry , I did not realize that it was WPF specific. I haven't worked in winforms for a while. It seems that Invoke is the right idea after all.